# JQuery replaceWith() function and event handlers in memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

Say you have this html code :

```
<button id="click-me" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

And you run this jQuery snippet:

```
var button = $('#click-me');

button.on('click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked !');
});

button.replaceWith('<button id="click-me" type="button">Click Me (Replaced)!</button>');
```

Of course the button will do nothing, because it was replaced with another button that has no click event handler bound to it, right ?.

**My question is:** Is the click event handler still exists somewhere in the memory? or, was it removed by the garbage collection process ?

Comment: As JQuery API defined for [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/): `The .replaceWith() method removes all data and event handlers associated with the removed nodes. `

Comment: @Sphinx Thank you so much, so I don't have to worry about memory leaks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the click event handler still exists somewhere in the memory? or, was it removed by the garbage collection process ?

No, the event never was bound it again because the function `replaceWith` removed the complete DOM of the previous element `button`.

**You can use event delegation to keep that event "bound" it to the element `#click-me`:**

```js
var button = $('#click-me');

$(document).on('click', '#click-me', function() {
    console.log('Clicked !');
});

button.replaceWith('<button id="click-me" type="button">Click Me (Replaced)!</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click-me" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ele, so I don't have to worry about memory leaks ?

Comment: @CryptoBird no, the JS engine releases the unreferenced objects for us.